# How to combat 9172 root access attemps to my server?

Tags: security, ubuntu, ssh, server, root

Today I've counted 9172 attempts to access to my server (debian) and another 6600+ attempts to another VPS (ubuntu 14.04).

I've reported the attemps by doing:

cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "Failed password" | grep "Apr 20" | wc -l

which reported a bunch of attempts such as

```
Apr 20 16:58:23 server sshd[684132]: Failed password for root from 43.255.190.155 port 46942 ssh2
Apr 20 16:58:23 server sshd[684159]: Failed password for root from 176.8.253.72 port 4550 ssh2
Apr 20 17:23:50 server sshd[693103]: Failed password for root from 58.218.199.49 port 56922 ssh2
```

Besides having a strong password for every user, is there a way I can fight back these attacks? I'm thinking by automatically blacklisting IPs after a few failed attempts or by automatically doubling the response time to a given IP every time it fails? Or other measures, keeping in mind I need the ssh service to be available to a public IP?

Thank you!

Comment: google + ssh auto blacklist is a good start

Comment: I'd recommend changing the ssh port from 22 to something in the thousands: that will greatly cut down the number of opportunists.

Comment: This is off-topic. It might be more appropriate for http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks, I agree actually, feel free to vote for migration

Comment: There's no automatic migration to those sites. You can delete the question and repost it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable root login from ssh and use another login for administration purposes.

Don't name your login 'admin', you'd get as many access attempts with it.

**Disabling ssh root login :**

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/security-tip-disable-root-ssh-login-on-linux/